# app requests being treated as reminder

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-app-requests

I am developing mobile app where user can invite friends through FB app (There is FB Application as well) requests.

When this implemented it worked great. Notification came under globe icon in friends FB. There is no implementation what happens when user click on that notification at that time.

After couple of days testing suddenly it stopped showing under globe but app requests being treated as reminders. Also request can be seen in appcenter/requests as well. But not under globe.

Now we added backend which installs FB app but still there is no showup of requests under globe

After lot of research in FB documentation, I found that app requests needs to be deleted by programmer. How this can be achieved?. I haven't stored those ids anywhere after sending app request.

Please help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this solution after going though lot of FB documentation.

For every app request, Facebook creates unique id in database.

These app requests can be seen at Globe icon, app center, reminders as well.

If received user clicks on pp request, its developer responsibility to remove that unique id from facebook and install app.

As we haven't removed unique ids then FB treating future our app requests as reminders not in notification.

Having removed all those ids now, it started to show up again in notification.